# How to calculate multiple integrals $\iiint x dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to understand how to solve/calculate integrals like these. I have some ideas but I don't know which way is correct.

First integral: $\int \int \int_D x dxdydz$ where D is limited by these surfaces: $z = xy$, $x+y=1$, $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$. My tries:

1: $ x \in [0,1]$ and  $ y \in [0,1]$ and $ z \in [0,\frac{1}{4}]$. $\frac{1}{4}$ because it is maximum for $ z = xy \wedge x+y = 1$. Then I have:

$\int \int \int_D x dxdydz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}x dz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot \frac{1}{4} dy = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1} x dy = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} x dx = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}|_{x=0}^{x=1} = \frac{1}{8}$

2:  $ x \in [0,1]$ and  $ y \in [0,1]$ and $ z \in [0,xy]$. I have:

$\int \int \int_D x dxdydz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{xy}x dz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1}x^{2}y dy = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} dx = \frac{1}{6}$

3: $ x \in [0,1]$ and  $ y \in [0,1-x]$ and $ z \in [0,xy]$. Then I have:

$\int \int \int_D x dxdydz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1-x}dy \int_{0}^{xy}x dz = \int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1-x}x^{2}y dy = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} (1-x)^{2} dx = \frac{1}{60}$

---

Second Integral:

$\int \int \int_D z \cdot \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} dxdydz$ where D is limited by these surfaces: $z=3$, $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4$,

---

And Third Integral

$\int \int \int_D x dxdydz$ where D is limited by these surfaces: $z=3$, $x=0$, $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$. This integral for me has no sense (because range of $z$ is not exactly determinate).

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Integral**

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{xy}x\,dz\,dy\,dz=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}x^2y\,dy\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^2 (1-x)^2 dx=\frac12\beta(3,3)=\frac1 {60}$$
**Second Integral**
$$x=r\cos\theta\quad,\quad y=r\sin\theta$$
$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}\right|=r$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3}r^2\,z\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=6\pi$$

Comment: How did you get $\;0\le\theta\le2\pi\;$ in the second integral if, as far as I can see, we're on the full cylinder of radius $\;2\;$ in the first octant $\;x=0,\,y=0,\,z=0$ ? Shouldn't it be $\;0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\;$ ?

Comment: Yes thank you so much